# Are there Bluetooth attacks on Smartphones that will not notify the user of the attack?

Tags: attacks, mobile, bluetooth

Are there Bluetooth attacks on Smartphones that will not notify the user of the attack?

Specifically forcing a reset or opening an application.

Comment: Well.. if you're not supposed to know the attack is happening..... how would we know?

Answer (score 1):

It amazes me that you did not search for keywords like bluetooth hacking or something similar.
Of course it possible - its called bluesnarfing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluesnarfing

Comment: Buddy, i want to explore it out.. links are ok.. but i want to get applications where i can real time

Comment: Bluesnarfing is illegal. If you want to perform it just for a prank this is the wrong place to ask for an advice. If you want to research it to secure your device you should start of with lots and lots of articles, not going straight to downloading applications. Not knowing what you are doing you can potentially harm the devices of your colleagues.

Comment: Some of the English of that wiki page you posted is pretty bad "After the release of this vulnerability vendors of mobile phone patch his Bluetooth implementation and at the date, there isn't any more phone vulnerable to this attack." It also doesn't provide any links to any implementations against smart phones and neither do you. Poor answer.

Comment: I admit. I did not spend much time at searching it. I just wanted to point what to search. Bluesnarfing is not a very researched topic.

Comment: I've actually just tried searching it quite a bit and as far as I can tell there isn't any methods to 'Bluesnarf' a smart phone, if you take smart phone to be an iPhone or Android based phone.